# How do I loop a blog-embedded video? (from Vimeo or elsewhere)

Tags: youtube, tumblr, vimeo

I created a short (4 second) video meant for looping on the web (via Tumblr) and saw two options.

1. Create an animated GIF
2. Embed and loop video hosted elsewhere (YouTube, Vimeo, etc.)

Software exists to convert from video to animated GIF, but you lose most of its image color palette and end up with large data files. Looping looked like a better option, since you only need to export and upload the original clip.

Plenty of hosting sites allow embedding on Tumblr, but stop after 1 play and show ads or "related videos." How can I host my video and loop its playback, without ads or other overlays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For YouTube, replace the video ID (1sRaZV21zb4) with your own ID and the video loops.

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/1sRaZV21zb4?fs=1&loop=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="390"></embed>
```

(ADDED BY ASKER): For Vimeo, replace the video ID (20278207) with your own ID and the video loops.

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20278207?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Confirmed: this code will loop a YouTube video on Tumblr embedded video. Only downside (compared to Vimeo) is that the play bar remains visible for YouTube. Maybe a code change would remove that, too?

Answer (score 1):

See [vimeorepeat.com](http://www.vimeorepeat.com/). From source code you can find simple javascript for implementing loop for Vimeo videos. I won't copy and paste it to here, because some people may claim copyright on it, even though that's rather ridiculous.

Comment: Just so I understand right, the hosting blog (Tumblr, Wordpress, etc.) would need to support inserting custom JavaScript, as taken from that page?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this after trying several different hosting sites and searching Google unsuccessfully. It's a simple solution using Vimeo and should work with any length of video.

1. Upload your video
2. Choose "embed" from your video's page on Vimeo.com
3. Choose customize embed options
4. Check (at least) "Autoplay" and "Loop" this video
5. Copy the Vimeo embed code
6. Add the embed code to your blog and confirm that it loops

This should save a lot of time and effort over creating an animated GIF, assuming viewers will have a live net connection to Vimeo. (GIFs download to your own computer, so don't need a streaming connection.)

Answer (score 1):

For YouTube to loop: go to http://jveo.net, paste the YouTube link in the textbox and click the **Repeat Youtube** button.

Note: I am affiliated with http://jveo.net

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the service you mentioned, otherwise the answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. See [this FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).